# How do I make my corners look like they are kinda white and popping out like the image below?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

How do I make my corners look like the image below?

[image]

Comment: That is because of a bevel. The reason why they turn white is the material is somewhat specular, so chances are the bevel is bound to catch the light at one of its angles and reflect it at the camera.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to enable *Cavity* under *Viewport Shading*. There is an arrow on the right of the viewport render, inside you will find *Cavity*.

[image]